# How to reorder a list of tidygraph objects based on a column in the list in R?

Tags: r, tidygraph

I have a list of `tidygraph` objects. I am trying to reorder the list elements based on a certain criteria. That is, each element of my list has a column called `name`. I am trying to group together the list elements that have identical `name` columns... but also I would like to group them in descending order of their count as well (i.e., the count of equal `name` columns in each list element). Hopefully my example will explain more clearly.

To begin, I create some data, turn them into tidygraph objects and put them together in a list:

```
library(tidygraph)
library(tidyr)

# create some node and edge data for the tbl_graph
nodes1 <- data.frame(
  name = c("x4", NA, NA),
  val = c(1, 5, 2)
)
nodes2 <- data.frame(
  name = c("x4", "x2", NA, NA, "x1", NA, NA),
  val = c(3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 7)
)
nodes3 <- data.frame(
  name = c("x1", "x2", NA),
  val = c(7, 4, 2)
)
nodes4 <- nodes1
nodes5 <- nodes2
nodes6 <- nodes1

edges <- data.frame(from = c(1, 1), to = c(2, 3))
edges1 <- data.frame(
  from = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 5, 5),
  to = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
)

# create the tbl_graphs
tg_1 <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes1, edges = edges)
tg_2 <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes2, edges = edges1)
tg_3 <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes3, edges = edges)
tg_4 <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes4, edges = edges)
tg_5 <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes5, edges = edges1)
tg_6 <- tbl_graph(nodes = nodes6, edges = edges)


# put into list
myList <- list(tg_1, tg_2, tg_3, tg_4, tg_5, tg_6)
```

So, we can see that there are 6 `tidygraph` objects in `myList`.

Examining each element we can see that 3 objects have identical `name` columns (i.e., `x4,NA,NA`).... 2 objects have identical `name` columns  (`"x4", "x2", NA, NA, "x1", NA, NA`).. and 1 object remains(`x1,x2,NA`).

Using a little function to get the counts of equal name columns:

```
# get a count of identical list elements based on `name` col
counts <- lapply(myList, function(x) {
  x %>%
    pull(name) %>%
    paste0(collapse = "")
}) %>%
  unlist(use.names = F) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  mutate(val = n():1) %>% 
  slice(1) %>%
  arrange(-val)
```

Just for clarity:

```
> counts
# A tibble: 3 × 2
# Groups:   value [3]
  value                  val
  <chr>                <int>
1 x4 NA NA                 3
2 x4 x2 NA NA x1 NA NA     2
3 x1 x2 NA                 1
```

I would like to rearrange the order of list elements in `myList` based on the `val` column in my `counts` object.

My desired output would look something like this (which I am just manually reordering):

```
myList <- list(tg_1, tg_4, tg_6, tg_2, tg_5, tg_3)
```

Is there a way to automate the reordering of my list based on the count of identical `name` columns?

**UPDATE:**

So my attempted solution is to do the following:

```
ind <- map(myList, function(x){
  x %>%
    pull(name) %>%
    replace_na("..") %>%
    paste0(collapse = "")
}) %>%
  unlist(use.names = F) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(ids = 1:n()) %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  mutate(val = n():1) %>% 
  arrange(value) %>% 
  pull(ids)

# return new list of trees
myListNew <- myList[ind]
```

The above code groups the list elements by the `name` column and returns an index called `ind`. I'm then indexing my original list by the `ind` index to rearrange my list.

However, I would still like to find a way to sort the new list based on the total amount of each identical `name` variable... I still haven't figured that out yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of testing, I eventually have a working solution.

```
ind <- map(myList, function(x){
  x %>%
    pull(name) %>%
    replace_na("..") %>%
    paste0(collapse = "")
}) %>%
  unlist(use.names = F) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(ids = 1:n()) %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  mutate(val = n():1) %>% 
  arrange(value) 

ind <- ind %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  mutate(valrank = min(ids)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(valrank, value, desc(val)) %>% 
  pull(ids)

# return new list of trees
myListNew <- myList[ind]
```

The above code arranges the list by `name` alphabetically. Then I group by the name and create another column that ranks the row. I can then rearrange the rows based on this variable. Finally I index by the result.